# force reinstall of 20.04 over top of existing 20.04

Tags: 20.04, reinstall

I successfully upgraded from 19.10 to 20.04. I then went looking for a few new themes and in an effort to test out the POP_OS theme, I accidentally installed the `ppa:system76/pop` PPA repo, and during an update if updated a tonne of stuff, including my kernel, libs, etc. I really only wanted the POP_OS theme, but now I feel I'm in a weird hybrid state. I am looking for a way for force a reinstall of a clean 20.04 over top, without completely wiping my installation out with a clean install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can at any time reinstall while leaving your current system in place with a live DVD/USB. In the installer, select "Something else". Assign the same root ("/") partition as you currently have, and make sure to **uncheck** the "Format" checkmark. Depending on your current setup, you may also need to assign other partitions to indicate your current situation to the installer (each time making sure you do *not* reformat).

This procedure reinstalls the entire system, including all your currently installed applications, with fresh system configuration while leaving your current user configuration and data in place.

Comment: It would be nice to have this as a pre-configured menu option

Comment: @andyczerwonka impossible, because the installer cannot know in case a system is configured differently.

Comment: it can interrogate when the root partition is mounted, it can find out where the OS is installed.

Comment: Its super important to remember the exact user as first image installed, and create the user/pass exactly the same in the second install

Answer (score 0):

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:system76/pop` did the trick!